# Dynamically decide salesforce object name and fields in SSIS Salesforce Integration Toolkit Connector

Tags: sql-server, ssis, salesforce, integration

I want to know is this possible to do in [SSIS Salesforce Integration Toolkit](https://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-salesforce).

I have installed microsoft visual studio 2015 with SQL server data tools.

I am trying to download salesforce objects data to local SQL server 2016 database. In which I have excel sheet with two columns **object name** and **fields** (separated by comma). 
[image]

So I used ForEach loop container to iterate over the list from excel sheet. And using row values I generated query string i.e. SOQL query.

I tried to provide dynamically generated SOQL query to **salesforce source connection** But its not working, salesforce source connection editor not taking the dynamic value instead showing error message as shown in below screenshot.

[image]

Kindly provide any valuable suggestions to resolve the issue.

I want to dynamically build SOQL query and provide this to Salesforce connector and retrieve data for all salesforce objects i.e offcourse inside loop container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the issue you are getting, can you please try to provide a default value for @[User:Fields] and @[User:Oname] to see if it makes any differences? By doing this, the component can have default fields and entity to initiate the metadata.

We would also like to mention that, since the metadata (columns in the Columns page) is defined in the design-time and cannot be changed dynamically during the runtime, so you cannot just simply change the fields in the SOQL query to update the columns during the runtime. This means that the fields need to be exactly the same for each iteration (i.e. entity).

Comment: Thanks lot for response, I am at right place with problem, Is there any workaround? I want to download all salesforce objects data with single SSIS package and using KingswaySoft Salesforce connector.

Comment: I am able to provide Object name dynamically with default value set. But as mentioned in answer it's not working for columns. Please suggest if there any workaround for columns.

Comment: As we've mentioned, the component metadata (columns) is defined during the design-time and this is how SSIS works, so unfortunately you cannot change it during the run-time. In this case, you may consider using one Salesforce Source component per object.